# UIActivityIndicatorView for long computational process

Tags: xcode, uiactivityindicatorview

I have a computational process that takes quite a bit of time to perform so a `UIActivityIndicatorView` seems appropriate. I have a button to initiate the computation.

I've tried putting the command `[calcActivity startAnimating];` at the beginning of the computation in an `IBAction` and `[calcActivity stopAnimating];` at the end of the computation but nothing shows.

Next, I created a new `IBAction` to contain the starting and stopping with a call to the computation `IBAction` and a dummy for loop just to give the startAnimating a little chance to get started between the two. This doesn't work either.

The skeletal code looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)computeNow:(id)sender {
    [calcActivity startAnimating];
    for (int i=0; i<1000; ++i) { }
    [self calcStats];
    [calcActivity stopAnimating];
    }

- (IBAction)calcStats {
    // do lots of calculations here
    return;
    }
```

Comment: You should never perform long calculations in your main thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, as I commented, you should never performe complex calculations in your main thread. It not only leads to situations like yours, your app might also be rejected from the store.

Now, the reason for the UIActivityIndicatorView not being updated is, that the UI doesn't actually update itself e.g. when you call `[calcActivity startAnimating];` Instead, it gets updated after your code ran through. In your case, that means that `startAnimating` and `stopAnimating` are getting called at once, so nothing really happens.

So, the 'easy' solution: Start a new thread, using either [this techniques](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/CreatingThreads/CreatingThreads.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH15-SW2) or, probably better, [GCD](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the nudge, Phlibbo. I'm new to this game and appreciate all the help. I didn't comprehend all the info on the links you provided, but it did prod me to search further for examples. I found one that works well. The IBAction 'computeNow' is triggered by the calculation button. The code now looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)computeNow {
    [calcActivity startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(calcStats) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
    return;
}

- (void) calcStats {
    // Lots of tedious calculations
    [calcActivity stopAnimating];
}
```

Comment: You should edit your post instead of 'commenting' in an answer. Also, if it was helpful, please accept my answer :)